# Save plot in matplotlib format

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, format, save

I have a plot in Python, and I would like to save it such that I would be able to open it with the functions of `pyplot` without having to re-run the file.

I know for example that Matlab allows user to save plot in fig format. This way we can fully re-use the plot.

I know I can save it in png, jpeg, etc. But this is not what I want. I want to slide in the plot and zoom.

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: You can try to [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) the figure

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether there is a more efficient way to do this, but generally you can save python objects of any kind to text files using pickle. In your case, you could write:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

fig = plt.figure()
# plot stuff to fig
with open("path/to/file/", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(fig, file)
```